# PHP MySQL check for session

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have this code for login.php , that connects to database, and let me in or not. Code by itself works, BUT checking if user is logged in is not working. (I don't want to build login form, and some guy just type domain.com/welcome.php and gets in) anyway, here is my login.php code. When i enter wrong username or password, it displays error, but when I enter correct one, it just push me back to index.php which is login form.

```
<?php

// Get values from form
$username = $_POST ['username'];
$password = $_POST ['password'];

// Prevent MySQL injection
$username = stripcslashes($username);
$password = stripcslashes($password);

// Connect to database
mysql_connect("domain.com", "sqlusername", "sqlpassword");
mysql_select_db("database");

// Query the database for user
if ( ($username != null || $username != "") && ( $password != null || $password != "" ) ) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'")
        or die("Failed to query members " .mysql_error());

    if ( mysql_num_rows($result) == 1 ) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
            header("location:/welcome.php");
    } else {
        header("location:/?error=true&msg=2");
    }
} else {
    // Handle empty entries
    header("location:/?error=true&msg=1");
}

?>
```

And here is my page that users with username and password will login.

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);

if (isset ($_SESSION['user'])){
    $username = $_SESSION['user'];

} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();

}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Loged in</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div>
        WELCOME <?php $username /?>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you have in your session array when you `var_dump` it?

Comment: Please come in 2016 and don't use mysql. By the way it seems you never start the session in your login.

Comment: That var_dump is some guy told me to put in.. it's should work, what he said..

Mattia - use MySQLi?

Comment: in If statement change `| |` with `&&` because it will just check if $username is not null and will skip 2nd part of if

Comment: Marko Kunić - urađeno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have missed `session_start();` while setting the session value, means in your `login file`.

it has to be something like this

```
<?php
session_start(); //session starts here
// Get values from form
$username = $_POST ['username'];
$password = $_POST ['password'];
//the other stuff what you wanna do with your username and password
// without starting out session, you cannot set any session values.
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is correct.. it's working now! :) also , Welcome (user) have some error, if you could point me in right direction.. Thanks again.

Comment: `WELCOME <?php $username /?>` check this line, change to `WELCOME <?php echo $username; ?>`

Comment: Also, I don't mean to be pushy but is it too much trouble to check is it male or female and displays welcome message according to that. Since in my language if it's female it should say "Dobrodošla" , but if it's male then it's "Dobrodošao". I have already set up SQL to have column with male or female with ENUM value.

Comment: as the `username` what you set in session is unique, run a query to grab the logged user's record, then check for the field `gender`. give a condition then `$welcomeMsg = $userGender==1 ? "Male Message" : "Female Message";` or vice versa. and then display the variable `$welcomeMsg` using `echo` or `print`

Comment: Thanks again! Very appriciated.